# Using <a/> tag with a sticky navbar takes me to the wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I have a `<Navbar/>` custom Component in React with the following CSS

```
.navbar-container {
    background-color: #111d5e;
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And I have some sections on the same page, and the Navbar holds links to those sections like this: `<a href="#projects">Projects</a>`. The problem is, when I click on the Projects link, it takes me to the Projects section, but it scrolls a bit too far down, and hides the "Projects" title behind the sticky navbar.. How do I fix this?

App.js - here you can see my Navbar and my sections

```
<div className="main">
                <Navbar />
                <div className="content">
                    <section id="home">
                        <h1>Home</h1>
                    </section>
                    <section id="about-me">
                        <h1>About me</h1>
                    </section>
                    <section id="projects">
                        <h1>Projects</h1>
                    </section>
                    <section id="contact">
                        <h1>Contact</h1>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div style={{ height: 700 }}></div>
            </div>
```

And this is the Navbar itself:

```
            <div className="navbar-container">
                <div className="navbar-name-flex">
                    <h1>Page Name</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="navbar-links-flex">
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#about-me">About me</a>
                    <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
                    <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: please add your sample code to snippets or share html code if possible so we can understand this situation.

Comment: @Mohammad added

Answer (score 2):

you should put a span tag inside title with the proper id.

```
<h3><span id="one"></span>one</h3>
```

Now use 2 lines of CSS to position them properly.

```
h3{ position:relative; }
h3 span{ position:absolute; top:-200px;}
```

Change the top value to match the height of your fixed header (or more). Now I assume this would work with other elements as well.

Comment: Would I have to give absolute position to every section in this case?

Comment: yes, in your case what's going on when you click a tag your section is at the top and so is your navbar so your navbar is hiding your title